# Database transactions

Tags: django, transactions

I have a view which reads the excel sheet and saves the data. I need a way if there is any error happens(500) in that view the database transactions should not commit and hence they should rollback.

I use the following code but it saves the data before the errors comes. My tasks is if there is any error in views the database should rollback.

from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success 
def upload_data(request):
  ..... and so on .....
  obj.save()

Error comes here on this line
  Want rollback the database as it
  was before this view was called
  obj1.save()
  If error is here noting should be saved.
Thanks

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: I am using Django 1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Django's documentation on transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/), if you're using Django 1.6, I'd wrap the whole view in `@transaction.atomic`:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
```

If you want this behavior for your whole app, set `ATOMIC_REQUESTS=True` in your database configuration, as described in that documentation.

Otherwise, if you're on 1.5 and not getting the behavior you expect, you could switch to `@transaction.commit_manually`, wrap the whole view in a `try` block, and do a `commit()` or `rollback()` explicitly. It's not elegant, but it might work if you want fine-grained control of when exactly commits happen.

Comment: I am using Mysql and i tried your approach also. But it is not working. I put try except block on each save object also

Answer (score 0):

try to put @transaction.commit_on_success just top of your view. So, if you get an error within that view function it will rollback else commit your work.